# How to create new worksheets with PHPExcel using kohana 3.2

Tags: php, phpexcel, worksheet, kohana-3.2

```
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2->load('ExampleSpreadsheettest.xlsx'); 
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4', 'first page')
        ->setCellValue('A1', '5')
        ->setCellValue('A2', '6')       
        ->setCellValue('A3', '7');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('ExampleNew.xlsx');
```

Above code is working but i want to add more worksheets instead of single work sheet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the PHPExcel documentation might help: the addSheet() method is used to add a new worksheet.

```
$excel2->addSheet();
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(1);  
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4', 'second page') ;
```

Comment: Just use:  $excel2->createSheet(1);  //where 1 is the number of the worksheet (counting from zero!)... or see PHPExcel - creating multiple sheets by iteration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850013/phpexcel-creating-multiple-sheets-by-iteration